# Clone a running fileystem to an image file

Tags: linux, filesystems, backup

How can I clone a running Linux file system (Debian 10) to a `.img` file? I want to flash that to another SSD and want the new system to run exactly the same. Clonezilla did not work for me. The new machine hardware will be exactly the same.

Comment: It feels wrong to clone a running system and I would always prefer to boot from some USB device and clone the unmounted volume, but when a couple of times I had no other possibility on my embedded devices, I experienced no problems simply `dd`ing the running system volume (piped through `gzip`) to an image file.

Comment: What @Philippos wrote or, at strict minimum, achieve that sort of thing in single user mode.

Comment: @Philippos. It doesn't have to be strictly running. I can boot from other live cd. I tried using clonezilla and failed so I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: The `dd` method you mentioned should work. However, the resulting image is not ISO image, it is just the byte-for-byte copy of the whole disk. If you want to use it as you would use an ISO image, it will obviously fail. You have to `dd` it back to the target drive. It is however strange that `dd` created output file of "half the size" - I guess, half the size of the drive that was cloned? This might mean filesystem on your disk is somehow corrupted. Did you check it?

Comment: @raj FAT32 has 4GB limit hence the 4GB file. Also, I don't want to copy the entire 30GB drive to another 30GB img file. I only want make image of used disk space which is around 7.5 GB

Comment: @Cruise5 Clonezilla should be able to do just that. You said Clonezilla was not able to unmount partition. It is strange because when you run Clonezilla off a live CD (as the docs recommend) there shouldn't be any disk partitions mounted in the first place, so there's nothing to unmount.

Comment: @raj I never said Clonezilla was not able to unmount the partition. I said that it was giving me cannot read root partition error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy whole block device as an image with dd or ddrescue or even cat (let's assume destination is /dev/sdb)

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/master.img
(...)
$ dd if=/mnt/master.img of=/dev/sdb
```

and it should work as you will have whole partition table boot sector and the file system itself copied 1 to 1 onto new medium. It will also clone whole partition table and the structure of your primary drive.

This image is not iso, and you shouldn't think of it this way.
In simplified terms your drive and subsequently image will contain whole drive structure:

```
|<-- sda ------------------------------------------------------------->|
|                            |<-- sda1 --->|<-- sda2 --->|<-- sdaN --->|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-+=============+=============+...==========+
| MBR, part.table, boot.sect | partition 1 | partition 2 | partition n |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-+=============+=============+...==========+
```

and your new drive will have it too.

You don't need anything fancy to do it apart from root privileges to copy your primary and write to destination block device.

You can also make the image of system partition (let's say it's /dev/sda1), make a new partition table on your destination drive, make sure your system partition is at least as big as image, then copy sda1.img to /dev/sdb1 and make it bootable with boot manager of your choice. But it's more work especially in scenario like yours.

--
Assuming you only need that first partition, as said in comment you can also copy first part of /dev/sda, containing partition table/boot loader + first partition (/dev/sda1) and copy it over to your destination.

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/master1.img bs=1M count=7600
(...)
$ dd if=/mnt/master1.img of=/dev/sdb
```

```
|<-- sda -----------------------------------
|                            |<-- sda1 --->|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-+=============+
| MBR, part.table, boot.sect | partition 1 |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-+=============+
```

Partition table will be somewhat wrong as it will contain partitions that don't exist and may need to be fixed in future but it will work. It's not elegant but will work.

Comment: The only problem is that I don't want the entire 30GB disk to be copied over. I only want the partitions copied as an .img file to an USB drive. The source file system is around 7.5GB and I want the destination image file to be the same. I formatted the USB with exFAT to take care of max 4GB limit of FAT32

Comment: @Cruise5 Do I understand correctly that the whole disk is 30 GB but the partition do you want to copy is 7.5 GB? Then `dd` only that partition plus the partition table and bootloader area (before the first partition start, use `count=` argument to `dd`). Or is the partition 30 GB and the used space within the partition is 7.5 GB? In that case you can't use `dd` as you don't know which blocks are used and which not. `dd` the partition table and bootloader (as above) and then `tar` the rest of the filesystem.

Comment: Sou you have to format disk, make, let's say, first partition at least 7.5GB, copy `sda1.img` to `/dev/sdb1`, and make new boot sector on `/dev/sdb` so it boots from `sdb1`.

Comment: Alternatively copy first 7.6GB for `/dev/sda` > `sda.img` and `cat sda.img > /dev/sbd`. You will have wrong partition table, which you can fix later, but it will work.

Comment: @tansy The entire filesystem containing three partition is total 7.5 GB. There is `/` partition which is around 6.5 GB. The physical disk is 30GB but I want the backup image of only used space. I have to look at the last sector from from LiveCD environment and tell dd to stop after that sector. Not copy the rest of the empty blocks.

Comment: So 7.6GB was right approximation, and is likely to be enough. Unless your partitions are scattered across whole drive, then you'll have to move them towards the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Make a **backup** (with `Bacula`, `TimeVault`, `Timeshift` for example, even `Clonezilla` should be able to make a proper backup) to a NAT/USB. Then boot from LiveCD/LiveUSB on a new machine, and *restore* from the backup.

Comment: Can those tools make a `.img` file into an external usb drive because that's my goal? `Clonezilla` is not working. It giving me a cannot read partition error.

Comment: That's because `Clonezilla` uses `partclone` to make its partition images, which requires that the partitions are unmounted.

Comment: @Cruise5, So, is your goal is to make an `.img` file. Or your goal is to make a copy of the system on another machine? If you just must have `.img` - LiveCD on first machine, `Clonezilla` on it - and you have your `.img`. But is it really your goal?

Comment: @WhiteOwl. Yeah, my goal is to make some changes in the current machine and make a `.img` file so that it can be flashed to an SSD and next time I make a change, do the same thing.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Well I burned the iso of clone zilla and booted from it and it gave me a message that all partitions are unmounted. The error came later.

Comment: Which partition is it complaining about? Is this a dual-boot (with Windows) system?

Comment: @ajgringo619 The root partition of the linux that I am trying to clone to. There is no windows involved here.

Answer (score 0):

The program **ukopp**, which you can find as an apt package `apt install ukopp`. It is a GUI that will backup/store your system/files to an external drive, usually USB. From there you should be able to use the image on the USB to "flash" your other SSD.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to clone a whole drive, partition with data or an os on a drive is the `dd` command.

In my opinion `dd` is the best for clone/backup of devices/partitions.

`dd` will clone everything bit per bit.

**Before you start experimenting and trying out different tools, I would do a full backup/clone of the device to another with `dd`, if you have the option, and check if the backup/clone works.**

If your whole devices is **encrypted** with `luks` as an example, you can do a whole clone and flash to your new device, that will work too!

If you work with mounted fuse/sshfs you can backup/clone directly to this network folders too.

You can list all your block devices with `lsblk`

Example:

1. if your drive is /dev/sda and you wanna store/backup/clone on a directory or storage

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/user/osbkp.img bs=1M status=progress
```

You don't need **name.img** it can be **os123.bkp** too

2. do a live clone of a running system to target drive without creating an image.

source is /dev/sda and target is /dev/sdb

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress
```

Sometimes you create the new backup/clone to your new drive but you can't start from this device, than try again with dd(nothing works 100%)

3. clone the image to a new drive, where target is /dev/sdb

```
dd if=/home/user/osbkp.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress
```

4. clone a given partition

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/user/part1.img bs=1M status=progress
```

Explain:

**if=INPUT/SOURCE**

**of=OUTPUT/TARGET**

**bs=BLOCKS SIZE FOR COPY**
There are different blocksize that can be used i prefer 1MB, you can speed the process up or slow done with this setting, you have to find by yourself what is the best option

**status=progress STATUS IN REALTIME**

5. if you work with fat* as storage you can splitt the files, take a look at that posts too:

[Break up a dd image into multiple files](https://serverfault.com/questions/86808/break-up-a-dd-image-into-multiple-files)

[Creating a 80GB image with dd on a FAT32 drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/205621/creating-a-80gb-image-with-dd-on-a-fat32-drive)

There are a few thinks that you have to keep in mind:

**0.** dd will clone everything of this devices.

Your drive is `/dev/sda` and you clone this

with 5 partitions

`/dev/sda1`
`/dev/sda2`
`/dev/sda3`
`/dev/sda4`
`/dev/sda5`

You will get one file from /dev/sda with all this partitions, mbr, gpt, etc..

**1.** You can clone to every drive/storage

- You can clone from a harddisk to usb, or usb to harddisk, etc.. and
  run your cloned os from your new device

**2.** Your running target devices must have the same size or must be bigger

- you can't clone a bigger device to a smaller drive or clone only the used space of a partition
- **Example:**
  Your partition to clone is 8 GB but your os on the partition is only 1GB
  so you have free space of 7 GB, your target where you wanna clone to run your os is 4GB, this is not possible! You will clone the whole device with dd to your new drive you can't resize this.

If you clone to a bigger devices  you can create a new partition with the remaining space and mount/use that on your new device/os.

Take care if you try to merge the remaining space to your given partition!

**3.** The best way is to use a live system or other linux systems
and than plugin your drives and clone from target to source or from target to storage

**4.** every device has it's unique uuid and a label name that identified the device
if you clone drive a to b and you have both drives in one pc and you try to boot one of them with the label name or uuid, check grub or your bootmanager you will get a problem or you boot the wrong os.

You can check this with `blkid` and other commands.

You can change that and generate a new uuid, label, etc.. but be careful

**5.** You don't need to format the drive where your cloned image will run the dd will destroy/delete everything an create the new mbr, gpt, format, filesystem etc. from the given backed os

The other way is to create a blank os and copy all folders and files that you need.

There are a lot of tutorials for that.

**Check for how to create a linux system backup with `rsync`**

[How To Backup Your Entire Linux System Using Rsync](https://ostechnix.com/backup-entire-linux-system-using-rsync/)

[Full system backup with rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/rsync#Full_system_backup)

Create your basic clones with dd and do your stuff, but later i mean it is better to clone/copy only the changed files.

In GNU/LINUX everything is a File.

Answer (score 0):

I general, you cannot clone a running file system, because you'll get inconsistent data. Some changes may still be in memory, and even if you `sync`, other changes may be coming in.

If your filesystem supports snapshots (e.g. as in `btrfs`), however, you can make a snapshot of the current state of your filesystem, keep the system running on the original "branch", and then clone the static snapshot.

> To clarify my objective: I have a 32-bit Debian 10 installed on a small board. It is running some customized apps. I want to make some changes to and create a .img file.

So try to unmount the filesystems where you made the changes, and then clone them. This depends a lot on what file systems you have on what mount points, where the changes are, and if there are changes on the root filesystem, and on your general setup. It's impossible to answer generically.

Comment: The question is how to clone the umounted filesystems to an .img file on an external hard drive.

Comment: @Cruise5 The title of the question clearly says "Clone a **running** fileystem to an image file". "Running" means "mounted". If the question is about cloning an unmounted filesystem (which shouldn't be a problem in the first place, and there is a gazillion ways to do it, and it's also easy to google, and this question then probably is a duplicate), OP should change the title.

Comment: I am sorry but two of the "gazillion" ways (Clonezilla, Rescuezilla) didn't work. None of the programs mentioned in the comments here mention a way of how to create an `.img` file of only the used space, not the entire disk. Those programs create a number of files that can be restored using the same software. My title clearly says "image file".

Comment: And there also is a ton of formats for virtual disks, and many are called image-something-or-other, so if you have a particular image format in mind, please specify. Usually the assumption is that if you "want to flash something to SSD", you copy the complete partition, raw (which is why you see `dd` in some of the answers). If you want your system to work off some compressed format, then you need to include additional steps, no "just use this tool and it'll all work" approach is going to get you there.

Comment: And you won't be able to unmount the root partition in a running system, which means that you need to re-create that in some other way (for example in the same way you created it on your existing system), even if you can unmount and clone the other volumes.